# Decision Tree Interpretation (Titanic Data)

Tags: machine-learning, decision-tree, interpretation

I'm fairly new to `decision trees` and have a bit of trouble interpreting them when I move down branches. I have a few questions regarding the plot that was made on R. The response variable is `Survived` (`Yes`/`No`), which is to be predited by age, fare, number of siblings, and number of parents I attached a decision tree below using Kaggle's `Titanic` data-set.

1. What do the different colors of green/blue mean?
2. How do I interpret the leaf nodes?
3. I understand the very top node inteprets to 38% survived, 62% did
   not survive, and 100% of the population is in that bucket. If I move
   to the right...how would I interpret Bucket #3? And if I kept going,
   Bucket #6? Etc etc...

[Titanic Decision Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDM75.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) A node is colored according to the majority class corresponding to the node. The nodes that have majority class label as `no` (not survived) is colored green, otherwise blue (`yes` or survived).

2) Let's interpret the leftmost leaf node at he bottom. `83%` of the datapoints corresponding to the node has class label `no` and `17%` has class label `yes`. This nodes contains `62%` datapoints from the entire dataset.

3) Bucket #3 can be similarly interpreted: `26%` of the datapoints corresponding to the node has class label `no` and `74%` has class label `yes`. This nodes contains `35%` datapoints from the entire dataset. If you compute the weighted proportion of the `no` labels for node #2 and #3, you will get `0.65*0.81+0.35*0.26=0.6175~0.62`, which is the proportion of the data in the root node that contains the label `no`.

Comment: Really helpful, thank you. Would this interpretation of Bucket #3 be valid?

1) 74% survived if they were female (within 35% of the data)
2) 26% did not survive if they were female (within 35% of the data)